# Excel Date Look Up Function

Tags: excel-formula, lookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgUlm.png)
I have a range of dates in the column pasted above.. basic.

I want to look up the year end interest rate from this table which is really a range of dates.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s9TC.png)

so 12/31/2015 = 0%, 12/31/2016= 0% 12/31/2017 = 4.3%, 12/31/2018 = 4.3% etc.

How would one do this?

I was trying to use Lookup without much success. I do not have the typical date tables that I see used in examples rather I have the dates inclusive in a range and the related interest rate in the next column over.